# Reference 2 rows on same column/table, from a different table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a stat tracking webpage for a virtual hockey league on Xbox. I have my basic table layout setup, but I am struggling with how to create the query that will allow me to show the schedule. Below is my basic table layout, and what I'd like to do is have it display something like:

Game 1:
 New York vs Chicago
 Detroit vs Boston

Game 2:
 Boston vs New York
 Chicago vs Detroit

```
SELECT homeTeam.name AS HOME_TEAMNAME
FROM GameSchedule Sched

INNER JOIN GameStats GameStatsHome
ON Sched.ID = GameStatsHome.gameSchedule_ID
AND Sched.homeTeam_ID = GameStatsHome.team_ID

INNER JOIN Team homeTeam
ON homeTeam.ID = gameStatsHome.team_ID
```

I realize where I'm running into the problem is trying to pull the Team.name for both GameSchedule.awayTeam_ID and GameSchedule.homeTeam_ID. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I feel like I'm close..but then again, I have no idea what I'm doing, and have spent about 3 days trying to figure this one query out. I think if someone can point me in the right direction, I should be good for the rest of what I need... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Table: Team
-----------------------------------------------------------
| ID | name       | abbreviation | conference | division |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | New York  |      TMA     |      1     |     1    |
|  2  | Chicago   |      TMB     |      1     |     1    |
|  3  | Detroit   |      TMC     |      1     |     1    |
|  4  | Boston    |      TMD     |      1     |     1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------

Table: GameSchedule
------------------------------------------------
| ID | awayTeam_ID | homeTeam_ID | gameTime_ID |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1       |      2      |      1      |
| 2  |     3       |      4      |      1      |
| 3  |     4       |      1      |      2      |
| 4  |     2       |      3      |      2      |
------------------------------------------------

Table: GameStats
------------------------------------------
| ID | gameSchedule_ID | team_ID | goals |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |        1        |    1    |   5   |
| 2  |        1        |    2    |   3   |
| 3  |        2        |    3    |   6   |
| 4  |        2        |    4    |   1   |
| 5  |        3        |    1    |   2   |
| 6  |        3        |    4    |   5   |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So what are you trying to get as your result and what is your input?

Comment: The result i'm aiming for is to be able to display something like: Game 1:
New York vs Chicago
Detroit vs Boston

Game 2:
Boston vs New York
Chicago vs Detroit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide you both names

```
SELECT
    away.Name as AwayTeam,
    home.Name as HomeTeam
FROM
    Game_Schedule gs
    JOIN Team away ON t.ID = gs.AwayTeam_ID
    JOIN Team home ON t.ID = gs.HomeTeam_ID
```

You can do whatever you want to in these joins!

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to enter this into my sql line but getting an error of Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. The full 3 lines I'm trying to run are `code` $sql="SELECT
  away.name as AwayTeam, 
  home.name as HomeTeam
 FROM
  GameSchedule gs
  JOIN Team AS away ON Team.ID = gs.awayTeam_ID
  JOIN Team AS home ON Team.ID = gs.homeTeam_ID";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $rowset = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
`code`

Comment: ok, so i'm rusty with php too, but it actually failed at Unknown column 'Team.ID' in 'on clause'. I cahnged to t.ID as you had listed, and it did the same.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the query, there was a typo and the AS in the JOIN didn't exist